# Scraping landing pages of a list of domains

Tags: python, screen-scraping, scrapy

I have a reasonably long list of websites that I want to download the
landing (index.html or equivalent) pages for. I am currently using Scrapy (much love to the guys behind it -- this is a fabulous framework). Scrapy is slower on this particular task than I'd like and I am wondering if wget or an other alternative would be faster given how straightforward the task is. Any ideas?

(Here's what I am doing with Scrapy. Anything I can do to optimize scrapy for this task? )

So, I have a start URLs list like

start_urls=[google.com
                yahoo.com
                aol.com]

And I scrape the text from each response and store this in an xml. I need to turn of the offsitemiddleware to allow for multiple domains.

Scrapy works as expected, but seems slow (About 1000 in an hour or 1
every 4 seconds).  Is there a way to speed this up by increasing the
number of CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_SPIDER while running a single
spider? Anything else?

Comment: Nowadays there are excellent Python libs you might want to use - [urllib3](http://urllib3.readthedocs.org/) (uses thread pools) and [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/) (uses thread pools through urllib3 or non blocking IO through [gevent](http://www.gevent.org/))

Comment: Instead of programming, you could push a plaintext list of .index html pages into [HTTrack](http://www.httrack.com/page/9/en/index.html), and set the crawler to link to 0 pages deep. Note that this software will only create a copy of the index pages on your local machine, viewable offline.

Comment: In Scrapy 0.14+ you will want to adjust `CONCURRENT_REQUESTS` instead of the old `CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_SPIDER` setting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want a way to concurrently download multiple sites with python, you can do so with the standard libraries like this:

```
import threading
import urllib

maxthreads = 4

sites = ['google.com', 'yahoo.com', ] # etc.

class Download(threading.Thread):
   def run (self):
       global sites
       while sites:
           site = sites.pop()
           print "start", site
           urllib.urlretrieve('http://' + site, site)
           print "end  ", site

for x in xrange(min(maxthreads, len(sites))):
    Download().start()
```

You could also check out `httplib2` or `PycURL` to do the downloading for you instead of `urllib`.

I'm not clear exactly how you want the scraped text as xml to look, but you could use `xml.etree.ElementTree` from the standard library or you could install `BeautifulSoup` (which would be better as it handles malformed markup).

Comment: Do you think `.pop()` is thread safe? See [Are Python built-in container thread-safe?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2227169/95735)