# Is there a thread-safe (like Queue) set type in Python?

Tags: python, thread-safety, set, queue

I use `Queue.Queue` in my program, but it would be better if there was a type like `set`. I need the container to be thread-safe, but I do not want it to be ordered.

```
def init_query_pool(self):
    self._pool = Queue.Queue() // todo: replace Queue.Queue with set
    self._new_query_pool()

def _create_threads(self):
    sessions = session_util.load_sessions()

    for s in sessions:
        t = threading.Thread(target=self.gen_qs, args=(s,))
        t.start()

def gen_qs(self, session):
    params = self._init_params(session)
    while True:
        qs = self._pool.get()
        self._search(session, params, qs)
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. You can simply use `set`, right? I can't really see how you relate queues with sets, seem to be different concepts?

Comment: I think the question may be 'are sets thread-safe'? Possibly [a duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2227169/are-python-built-in-containers-thread-safe)

Comment: @freakish with my code, can you understand me ?

Comment: So is the reason for using set to avoid duplicates? Because otherwise set is quite inefficient compared to queue.

Comment: @freakish that is not the main reason, I just want to be unordered

Comment: @freakish and why set is inefficient?

Comment: OK, but what's the benefit? You can simply use `set` with `.pop()` instead of `.get()`. Sets are thread safe but `.pop()` is inefficient since searching and removing from sets (which `.pop()` does) requires hashing. While in queues `.get()` simply takes the entry from the head. Well, I'm not 100% sure that it performs worse, you should check this. Still, the conceptual difference is very important. Looking at such code I would not understand why you use set instead of queue.

Comment: @freakish thanks, I am downloading a set of url(these url have some order in them), may be an ordered url can be easily recognized