# Removing items from list while iterating over it

Tags: python, for-loop

There are two separate processes running in Python script. Both interact with a global variable `POST_QUEUE = []`

- Process 1 (`P1`) adds items to `POST_QUEUE` every 60 seconds. This can be anywhere from 0 to 50 items at a time.
- Process 2 (`P2`) iterates over `POST_QUEUE` via a for-loop at set intervals and performs an operation on the list items one at a time. After performing said operation, the process removes the item from the list.

Below is a generalized version of `P2`:

```
def Process_2():
    for post in POST_QUEUE:
        if perform_operation(post):
            Print("Success!")
        else:
            Print("Failure.")
        POST_QUEUE.remove(post)
```

Understandably, I've run into an issue where when removing items from a list that a for-loop is iterating over, it screws up the indexing and terminates the loop earlier than expected (i.e., before it performs the necessary operation on each post and removes it from `POST_QUEUE`).

**Is there a better way to do this** than just creating a copy of `POST_QUEUE` and having `P2` iterate over *that* while removing items from the original `POST_QUEUE` object? For example:

```
def Process_2():
    POST_QUEUE_COPY = POST_QUEUE[:]
    for post in POST_QUEUE_COPY:
        if perform_operation(post):
            Print("Success!")
        else:
            Print("Failure.")
        POST_QUEUE.remove(post)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are Python built-in containers thread-safe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2227169/are-python-built-in-containers-thread-safe)

Comment: Is the issue resolved? If so, please mark the correct answer as accepted or post and accept a solution of your own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you do not really need the indexes of the elements I would suggest something like this as an **easy** solution:

```
def Process_2():
    while len(POST_QUEUE):
        if perform_operation(post[0]):
            Print("Success!")
        else:
            Print("Failure.")
        POST_QUEUE.remove(post[0])
```

However this solution has a runtime of O(n^2) for every use of the loop since python needs to move every element in the list on every iteration.

So IMO a better implmentation would be:

```
def Process_2():
    reversed_post_queue = POST_QUEUE[::-1]
    while len(reversed_post_queue):
        if perform_operation(post[-1]):
            Print("Success!")
        else:
            Print("Failure.")
        POST_QUEUE.remove(post[-1])
```

that way you keep the order (which I suppose is important to you throughout this answer) while only moving the elements of the list once and resulting in a runtime of O(n)

finally, the best implementation IMO is to create or import a queue module
so that you could easily use the list as FIFO.

Answer (score 1):

You can loop through your list from right to left. This way, the removal of items will not cause issues to the loop. It's not a good idea in general to remove items from list while looping, but if you need to do it, going from right to left is the best option:

```
def Process_2():
    for i in range(len(POST_QUEUE)-1, -1, -1):
        if perform_operation(POST_QUEUE[i]):
            Print("Success!")
        else:
            Print("Failure.")
        POST_QUEUE.pop(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
while POST_QUEUE_COPY:
    post = POST_QUEUE_COPY.pop(0)
    if perform_operation(post):
        Print("Success!")
    else:
        Print("Failure.")
```

And processes don’t share data, threads do. So unless you are using something like `multiprocessing.Manager` or some shared-memory construct, I don’t think your current logic would work.